# Query to get the Top 2 from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this sql code:

```
SELECT   NoteOID = HCN.ObjectID,
         PatientOID = HCN.PatientID,
         PatientVisitOID = 0,
         CollectedDT = HCN.CollectedDT
FROM     HClinicalNote HCN WITH(NOLOCK)
where    HCN.enddt is NULL
         and HCN.visitid in (select distinct visitOID from @tblCensus)
order by HCN.PatientID,HCN.CollectedDT desc
```

that give these results:

```
 NoteOID    PatientOID     CollectedDT
 181382     890855         2011-09-14 21:31:00
 169115     890855         2011-09-12 18:38:00
 177466     890855         2011-09-09 19:49:00
 175150     890855         2011-09-07 19:34:00
 174057     890855         2011-09-06 19:25:00
 172429     890855         2011-09-04 09:00:00
 181387     13462666       2011-09-14 21:37:00
 182224     13462666       2011-09-14 13:24:00
 179269     13462666       2011-09-12 18:12:00
```

I would like to have the top 2 CollectedDT from each group of PatientOID.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using at least SQL-Server 2005, you ca use a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT  NoteOID = HCN.ObjectID,
           PatientOID = HCN.PatientID,
           PatientVisitOID = 0,
           CollectedDT = HCN.CollectedDT,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PatientOID ORDER BY CollectedDT ASC)
   FROM HClinicalNote HCN
   WHERE HCN.enddt is NULL
   AND HCN.visitid in (select distinct visitOID from @tblCensus)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Comment: @Arnault: If it working, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select T2.* from (SELECT  NoteOID = HCN.ObjectID, 
       PatientOID = HCN.PatientID,   
       PatientVisitOID = 0,   
       CollectedDT = HCN.CollectedDT,  
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PatientOID ORDER BY CollectedDT ASC)  
FROM HClinicalNote HCN   
WHERE HCN.enddt is NULL  
AND HCN.visitid in (select distinct visitOID from @tblCensus) ) as T2   
where T2.RN >=2
```

Comment: Two `WHERE` clauses? Apart from that i don't understand what this adds against my answer(he wants the first two of each group not skip the first 2 rows).